# Flutter shadow over other widgets

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

My base widget is a Column. The first element is a Container which has a BoxShadow. The second element is a ListView which builds several Card, depending on the context. If the scroll is 0 the shadow gets displayed. However when start scrolling, the card is "over" the shadow (higher z-index) and hides it.

unscrolled

[image: Shadow is visible when not scrolling]

scrolled
[image]

The shadow should stay always on top, over the Cards. How is this done?

Comment: Can you share some code ? And some UI of what is expected ? The screenshot looks so whitish and unable to understand much from the details. Sorry pal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, here is the concept of what is going wrong here.

The 1st child of `Column` is a `Container with shadow`. `Shadow` renders outside of the defined size. If you don't provide any spaces after this `Container` we won't be able to see the shadow. This space can be done by `Container margin` , `SizedBox` or `wrapping our list with` Padding`.  But now our main question is how we get shadow while` index=0`. I believe it is coming from` ListChildren`. They contain upper spaces, that's why we can see only the 1st time.

On Ui render priority starts from bottom to Top.

How to solve this problem:
We can provide space at the bottom of our container or assign `margin`(not padding), or  use a `SizedBox`  after the `container` providing the same amount of height as `shadow`.

1. providing bottom `margin` on the container.
2. adding a SizedBox with height of shadow.
3. wrapping our list with `Padding` and providing `top:`.

---

In this image,
our `shadow: white`, `background:amber`.

[image]

Demo code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColumnWithContainerShadow extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColumnWithContainerShadow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: double.infinity,
            ////* we dont need margin if we have padding on ListView
            // margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0, 12),
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
              ],
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text("Container A")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    333,
                    (index) => Container(
                      /// enable this margine and remove other spaces to see 1st child shadow.(shadow depend on children position)
                      // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                      height: 60,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      child: Text("$index"),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0, 12),
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
              ],
            ),
            child: Text("Bottom Container"),
          ),
          // Comment to close shadow
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this upper box in `Material` widget and provide an elevation.

Comment: Elevation is not actually a z-index

Comment: https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html

Comment: elevation is not related to z-index. It is called elevation but only provides a shadow

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

if you don't want container shadow to disappear on scroll remove the `ScrollNotification` and `NotificationListener`

There is a widget for that

You can use `ScrollNotification` with `NotificationListener`. Try [this](https://codepen.io/vettiyankan/pen/KKmBpJq);

Happy coding!

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  double blurRadius = 10.0;
  double spreadRadius = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: Get.width,
        height: Get.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0).copyWith(
                top: 62.0,
              ),
              child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                // ignore: missing_return
                onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                  if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                    setState(() {
                      blurRadius = 0.0;
                      spreadRadius = 0.0;
                    });
                  } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                    setState(() {
                      blurRadius = 10.0;
                      spreadRadius = 1.0;
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: ListView.builder(
                  // controller: _controller,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Container(
                          width: Get.width * .8,
                          height: 100.0,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text('child @ index : $index'),
                          )),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: Get.width,
                height: 60.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      blurRadius: blurRadius,
                      spreadRadius: spreadRadius,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('TOP CONTAINER'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```